# When I use pipes in Cygwin to connect commands, why don't the commands act "independently"?

Tags: cygwin, pipe

I'm a beginner to Cygwin. If I have:

```
cat output.txt | rm output.txt
```

I want to print out the results before I delete the file, but the results don't print even though these commands work find when inputted into Cygwin separately. Similarly:

```
grep -c 'ps' count.tmp | rm count.tmp
```

I want to show the results of `grep -c 'ps' count.tmp` before the `count.tmp` file is removed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't pipe them.

Do this instead:

```
cat output.txt ; rm output.txt
grep -c 'ps' count.tmp ; rm count.tmp
```

Edit:  The pipe (`|`) takes the standard output of one command and runs it into the standard input of another... like this:

```
# Get the number of lines
cat output.txt | wc -l 

or 

echo "Hello there" | tr -d' '
```

To JOIN commands, use either `;` or `&&`

The `;` will run the commands one after the other

```
echo Hi ; false; echo there
```

The `&&` will run the next command only if the previous command exited with a zero status code (success).

```
echo Hi && false && echo there
```

Answer (score 0):

Piped commands [can be run in any order](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run/37513), so there is no guarantee that the `rm` command won't be run first.  Use

```
cat output.txt && rm output.txt
```

which will only remove the file if the `cat` command succeeds.

Comment: This is an important distinction for people coming from a Windows/DOS background, where piped commands *do* run in order, passing stdio around in temporary files.